# Capture double click event in of the current window?

Tags: linux, bash, x11

I'd like to know whether a user performed a double click in a certain application (specifically, `evince`). I wrote some code to check if `evince` is running and then whether it is focused application. However, I do not know how to check whether double-click was performed.

```
pids=$(xdotool search --class "evince")
curr_id=$(xdotool getwindowfocus)

if echo ${pids[@]} | grep -q -w $curr_id; then 
    echo "is in array"
else 
    echo "is not in array"
fi
```

I am a Java developer but I'm ready to do the coding in bash or Python.

Comment: I was going to suggest `xdotool ... behave`, but it has an [open issue](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/163) specifically about mouse-click detection not working.